# How do to kill a timer started on a UserControl viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, timer, viewmodel

On the view model constructor for a UserControl I start a timer that runs every 30 seconds.
I need to find a way to stop it, when I close this class.

```
using System.Threading;
namespace uc
{
    class UserControlViewModel
    {
        Timer timer;

        public UserControlViewModel()
        {
            //Each five seconds check to see if the current user has had their module access permissions changed
            timer = new Timer(CheckUserModuleAccess, null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
        }

        private void CheckModuleAccess(object state)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Implement `IDisposable` and in the function `Dispose()` close the timer. Also create a destructor that closes the timer

Comment: @RononDex please add your example into an answer.

Comment: It's just to make clear that the timer gets disposed at the same time your model gets disposed. When something gets disposed doesn't mean it deconstructor fires. However in most cases you should be fine with the destructor

Comment: What do you mean by closing the class? Do you mean closing the UserControl? So are you asking that you need a way to stop the timer when the UserControl is closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a destructor to your viewmodel, that stops and destroys the timer:

```
using System.Threading;
namespace uc
{
    class UserControlViewModel
    {
        Timer timer;

        ...

        // Desctructor
        ~UserControlViewModel()
        {
            // Stop the timer when the viewmodel gets destroyed
            timer.Stop();
            timer.Dispose();
            timer = null;
        }
    }
}
```

If that doesn't do it, try to implement `IDisposeable` on your viewModel.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the solution you are looking for is the [Dispose Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace uc
{
    class UserControlViewModel : IDisposable
    {
        Timer timer;

        public UserControlViewModel()
        {
            //Each five seconds check to see if the current user has had their module access permissions changed
            timer = new Timer(CheckUserModuleAccess, null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
        }

        private void CheckModuleAccess(object state)
        {
            ...
        }

        public void Close()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing){
                if (timer != null) {
                    timer.Stop();
                    timer.Dispose();
                    timer = null;
                }
            }
        }

        ~UserControlViewModel()
        {
            Dispose(false);
        }

        #region IDisposable Members

        void IDisposable.Dispose()
        {
            Close();
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```